# Is there any way to alter the response of JSON API module?

Tags: 8

I am using [JSON API](http://drupal.org/project/jsonapi) module to expose data using REST API. I want to alter its response. I am trying to altering it using `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load`. If I change any existing property it shows the updated value. But if I try to add custom property it doesn't show the custom property in response. The two hooks I used are below:

```
function my_custom_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->set('flag_count', 10);
}

function my_custom_node_load($nodes) {
  foreach ($nodes as &$node) {
    $node->flag_count = 10;
  }
}
```

I need to know if there is any possible way to alter the json api response with custom properties?

Comment: Is flag_count a valid typed data property on the node? That might be removed by serialization.

Comment: Did you add your custom property as a custom (computed?) field of the node entity?

Comment: @mradcliffe yes I tried the hook according to Neograph734 answer. I guess you are right, JSON API is removing the property. Need to debug the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see how `jsonapi_entity_base_field_info` adds a computed property to the `file` entities. That should do.

If you don't want to create a *virtual* field, you can add a normalizer that only acts for that specific content type as a service. You'll need to use a higher priority than `serializer.normalizer.entity.jsonapi` (set to 21). Your custom normalizer can inherit from `Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer` and add your custom stuff in `getFields`.

Comment: Thanks hook_entity_base_field_info worked like a charm!! :)

Comment: Hi e0ipso, did you actually manage to alter the output of jsonapi module creating a new normalizer?

Comment: Things have changed quite a lot since this comment was written. Take a look at https://lullabot.com/articles/jsonapi-2

Comment: Long story short, the comment above is referring to the fact that you cannot override field normalizers from JSON:API anymore. You will get an error about it because the module considers normalizers part of internal API. There is a dirty trick that JSON:API Extras uses to get around this for its purposes -- it places code in the JSON:API module namespace to dodge the check -- but this is not a recommended pattern because the internal API of JSON:API could change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom normalizers to alter the JSON response.

Some good resources:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/how-the-serializer-works - An overview of how serializers work with normalizing.
- https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/using-normalizers-alter-rest-json-structure-drupal-8 - A good tutorial on using normalizers to alter REST JSON structure.

Comment: I could not make it work when using jsonapi module.

Comment: Things have changed quite a lot since this comment was written. Take a look at https://lullabot.com/articles/jsonapi-2

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should be using [`hook_entity_type_build`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/8.2.x) rather than `hook_entity_type_alter`, which states:

> Do not use this hook to add information to entity types, unless one of
>   the following is true:
>
> - You are filling in default values.
> - You need to dynamically add information only in certain circumstances.
> - Your hook needs to run after hook_entity_type_build() implementations.
>
> Use hook_entity_type_build() instead in all other cases.

And [EntityTypeInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityTypeInterface.php/interface/EntityTypeInterface/8.2.x) states

> Additional information can be provided by modules:
>   `hook_entity_type_build()` can be implemented to define new properties,
>   while `hook_entity_type_alter()` can be implemented to alter existing
>   data and fill-in defaults.

You might want to try something like this instead:

```
function my_custom_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  /** @var $entity_types \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] */
  $entity_types['node']
    ->set('flag_count', 10);
}
```

Comment: Great. I can see the property in `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load` but I guess JSON API removed this property. I need to debug some json api code itself.